# Rust calling fmt function directly

Tags: rust, formatter

I'm trying to implement different `Display` formats depending on arguments. Something like
`print_json()` and `print_pretty()`. I could of course implement it as a function returning string `print_json(&self)->String` but I'm wondering if it would be possible to have `print_json(&self,f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result` and `print_pretty(&self,f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result` instead. Then I could just call either of those functions depending on use case. But how do I obtain instance of `Formatter` directly? Ideally I would like to do something like

```
let mut string = String::new();
my_object.print_pretty(&mut string);
return string;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But how do I obtain instance of `Formatter` directly?

As far as I know, the only way to get a Formatter is to receive one by implementing `Display` or one of the other formatting traits.

I've implemented my own scheme to add more formatting options, based on this core trait:

```
/// Objects for which alternate textual representations can be generated.
/// These are analogous to [`Display`] and [`Debug`], but have additional options.
pub trait CustomFormat<F: Copy> {
    /// Wrap this value so that when formatted with [`Debug`] or [`Display`] it uses
    /// the given custom format instead.
    fn custom_format(&self, format_type: F) -> CustomFormatWrapper<'_, F, Self> {
        CustomFormatWrapper(format_type, self)
    }

    /// Implement this to provide custom formatting for this type.
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>, format_type: F) -> fmt::Result;
}
```

Types which wish to support additional formats implement `CustomFormat<F>` where `F` is a specific format type or format options; for your use case they could be `struct Json;` and `struct Pretty;`. Or, you could have two different traits — I just found that having a general-purpose one reduced code duplication.

As an implementation example, here I define a custom format for `std::time::Duration`. It looks just like a `Debug` or `Display` implementation except that it takes an extra format-options parameter (which it ignores because `StatusText` doesn't carry any extra options with it):

```rust
impl CustomFormat<StatusText> for Duration {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>, _: StatusText) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(fmt, "{:5.2?} ms", (self.as_micros() as f32) / 1000.0)
    }
}
```

Your code example using these tools would be:

```rust
let mut string = String::new();
write!(string, "{}", my_object.custom_format(Pretty)).unwrap();
return string;
```

The `"{}"` format string no longer controls the format; it's just a placeholder to invoke the format mechanism at all, via the `CustomFormatWrapper` which implements `Display` (and also `Debug`) to invoke the custom formatting:

```rust
pub struct CustomFormatWrapper<'a, F: Copy, T: CustomFormat<F> + ?Sized>(F, &'a T);

impl<'a, F: Copy, T: CustomFormat<F>> Debug for CustomFormatWrapper<'a, F, T> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        <T as CustomFormat<F>>::fmt(self.1, fmt, self.0)
    }
}

impl<'a, F: Copy, T: CustomFormat<F>> Display for CustomFormatWrapper<'a, F, T> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        <T as CustomFormat<F>>::fmt(self.1, fmt, self.0)
    }
}
```

This may be an over-engineered solution for your purposes. The key elements that are needed are the wrapper type which contains a reference to the value to be formatted, and that it *some* standard formatting trait such as `Display` to forward to your custom formatting trait (or, if you only ever want to custom-format one type, just the method on that object).

[Link to full source code in context](https://github.com/kpreid/all-is-cubes/blob/ce15ab52dc84c59efaa2f0b95b042cf65c201016/all-is-cubes/src/util.rs)